# How to build angular project without changing the maximum file size?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

Budget 40.00 kB was not met by 60.66 kB with a total of 80.66 kB.

I have been trying to solve anyComponentStyle max file limit.

I'm using Material UI and using indigo-pink.css in my component scss. But I can't build the project due to a limit size. How can I bypass this or is there any alternate way to achieve this css?

I've also try to load using material script but it also loads the same script at the end.

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

   @include mat.core();

   $primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
   $accent:  mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400); 
   $theme: mat.define-light-theme((
   color: (
    primary: $primary,
   accent: $accent
  ),
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
  density: 0,
   ));
   @include mat.core-theme($theme);
   @include mat.button-theme($theme);
   @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't build an app angular app that's 20KB. The minimal angular app is around 120KB.

Comment: I've updated the question. I have provided the max limit for anyComponentStyle.